# Is there a way to make a Line Renderer 3D in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I was wondering how can I make a Line Renderer between to points (joints) be a 3d model or at least how can I make a separate 3D model to follow the movement of the line renderer.
I have an AR project where, for a finger there is two points calculating the width of the finger and then a Line renderer comes in as a "ring" for the finger. And i was wondering how can make it a real ring by adding a 3D model

Answer (score 1):

As a mesh for such a "ring" would be called a "torus". Someone apparently made a neat script to generate those: https://www.devcoons.com/how-to-make-a-ring-using-torus-method-in-unity-3d/
Keep in mind that generating meshes is not super fast. So try to generate one at game start and scale in case you neeed it with different dimensions.

EDIT: This could be also interesting and more flexible: https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/TubeRenderer